# Is it possible to configure Vite to build for use inside Android app (CORS error)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules, vite

### Scenario

I'm using **Vue2** with **Vue CLI** as the bundling tool, now I want to migrate Vue CLI to **Vite** to enhance the development experience, and the migration process is somewhat successful (thanks to this [guide](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/)).

### Problem

Due to a specific reason, I need to keep the production build accessible statically, without any local server required (the web app should run simply by opening up the `index.html` file on my machine). And with this, I encounter the problem due to the fact that Vite bundles my code in ESM format that has to be served through some server to resolve CORS policy (error screenshot below). And hence the question: **Is it possible to configure Vite to build in plain JS rather than ESM?**

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

### Attachments

[image: error]

My `vite.config.js` as below if it helps:

```js
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { createVuePlugin } from "vite-plugin-vue2";

export default defineConfig({
  base: "",
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @use "sass:math";
        @import "@/scss/utils.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [createVuePlugin()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"]
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The question addresses a real problem in general. Though I'm not sure if there are valid reasons to enforce the usage without a webserver. This could by XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. To give some more context, the reason why I need it without a server is to embed the web app inside Android webview. This might sound like a dumb approach in the first place, but this Android app has been like this for years 

Comment: Makes sense, although I'm quite sure there are proper ways to do the same thing, https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader or something else. Vue app could use a router and so would be incompatible with file:/// any way